# CLM920_830 Restoring image after a bad Unpacking and repacking recovery or boot image

Tags: android, android-source, recovery

Good morning, this is the first time I resort to your wisdom.
As a practice, I was trying to modify the init.rc file on a custom device that runs Android 5.1 (CLM920_830). This device does not have buttons, it does have a screen but it is not a touch screen. achieve unpacking the boot image and leave a comment
(#test text) in the last line of the init.rc file, I think the problem was when packaging and flashing the image again.
According to the tutorial that I followed when copying, you must upload it with a new name "new_boot.img" instead of the original "boot.img" I uploaded it as boot.img and I suppose I overwrote it.
Now the device stays on the boot screen and I can no longer access it from ADB commands.
I use Ubuntu 14.04.
Is there a way to restart it or reinstall Android?

Thanks in advance.
This is the link to the tutorial I followed:
https://www.cnblogs.com/shangdawei/p/4514221.html

I tried to activate the emergency download mode as indicated in the manual (CLM920_830 硬件设计手 page 56) but the screen no longer shows booting... now it only appears off.
I tried to connect through adb and it doesn't appear in the list of available devices.